# What happens if you mount to a non-empty mount point with fuse?

Tags: linux, fuse

I am new to fuse. When I try to run a FUSE client program I get this error:

```
fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option
```

I understand that a mountpoint is the directory where you will logically attach the FUSE filesystem. What will happen if I mount to this location? What are the dangers? Is it just that the directory will be overwritten? Basically: what will happen if you mount to a non empty directory?

Comment: This happened to me. I noticed that i had saved some files by mistake under the directory that i try to mount. I just deleted them and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 31):

You need to make sure that the files on the device mounted by fuse will **not** have the same paths and file names as files which already existing in the nonempty mountpoint. Otherwise this would lead to confusion. If you are sure, pass `-o nonempty` to the mount command.

You can try what is happening using the following commands.. (Linux rocks!)  .. without destroying anything..

```
// create 10 MB file 
dd if=/dev/zero of=partition bs=1024 count=10240

// create loopdevice from that file
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 ./partition

// create  filesystem on it
sudo e2mkfs.ext3 /dev/loop0

// mount the partition to temporary folder and create a file
mkdir test
sudo mount -o loop /dev/loop0 test
echo "bar" | sudo tee test/foo

# unmount the device
sudo umount /dev/loop0

# create the file again
echo "bar2" > test/foo

# now mount the device (having file with same name on it) 
# and see what happens
sudo mount -o loop /dev/loop0 test
```

Comment: by the mount command do you mean this? FUSE(FuseHandler(a), b, foreground=True)  Do I add -o nonempty to that call?

Comment: Are you using a command line tool or a programming language to control fuse?

Comment: I am calling a python file that imports pyfuse

Comment: However, you might try the steps I've listed in order to see what is going on if there are files with the same name when mounting... and play around. at the end I assume it makes no difference if you are using fuse or a *regular* mount... Also it should make no difference when using a programming language or not.. The most portable and secure way will still being: "mount into empty folder"

Comment: `google-drive-ocamlfuse -o nonempty ~/gdrive` worked. `google-drive-ocamlfuse` creates `~/.gdfuse/default`.  In that dir is a `config` file. Can I add a `nonempty` setting to the `config` file?

Comment: users should not *disconnect* gdrive in thunar. Instead, *unmount* like this: `fusermount -u ~/gdrive` https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: @hek2mgl `sudo echo "bar" > test/foo` gives me `bash: test/foo: Permission denied`. Why?

Comment: @patryk.beza That's because the redirection `> test/foo` will be executed by the current shell and with the permissions of the user who executes the script, not with sudo. You can use `tee` instead: `echo "bar" | sudo tee test/foo`. PS: Thanks for spotting this problem!

Comment: @hek2mgl Two more things: (1) I don't know why `sudo umount /dev/loop0` (which is mounted in `test`) gives `umount: /dev/loop0: not mounted.` even though it's listed as mounted in `mount` output. `sudo umount test` works fine. (2) You assume that `/dev/loop0` is unused which was not true in my case – I needed to get first unused `loop` device by running `sudo losetup -f` as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1367742/losetup-does-not-find-first-unused-loop-device-and-fails-to-list-busy-devices).

Comment: One more thing: I need to use [`mkfs.ext3`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext3) instead of [`e2mkfs.ext3`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mke2fs) (there is no such a package on my `Ubuntu` 18.04.2 LTS). It seems that this is the same software named differently on different Linux distros.

Comment: That's fine, it was just an example to create a filesystem (of arbitrary type).

Comment: is this only when writing to files? or will it also cause issues reading from files? for example say i mount my .ssh for different config files

Comment: I am using fstab to mount this partition. How would I add the `-o nonempty` option?

Answer (score 14):

Just add `-o nonempty` in command line, like this:

```
s3fs -o nonempty  <bucket-name> </mount/point/>
```

Comment: after mounting nonempty dir how can i sync data from droplet to Space object?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently nothing happens, it fails in a non-destructive way and gives you a warning.
I've had this happen as well very recently. One way you can solve this is by moving all the files in the non-empty mount point to somewhere else, e.g.:

```
mv /nonEmptyMountPoint/* ~/Desktop/mountPointDump/
```

This way your mount point is now empty, and your `mount` command will work.

Comment: The only answer that actually **answers** the original queston!

Answer (score 3):

For me the error message goes away if I unmount the old mount before mounting it again:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/point
```

If it's not already mounted you get a non-critical error:

```
$ fusermount -u /mnt/point

fusermount: entry for /mnt/point not found in /etc/mtab
```

So in my script I just put unmount it before mounting it.

Answer (score 1):

Just set "nonempty" as an optional value in your `/etc/fstab`

For example:

```
## mount a bucket
/usr/local/bin/s3fs#{your_bucket_name}  {local_mounted_dir}  fuse _netdev,url={your_bucket_endpoint_url},allow_other,nonempty 0 0
 
## mount a sub-directory of bucket, Do like this:
/usr/local/bin/s3fs#{your_bucket_name}:{sub_dir}  {local_mounted_dir}  fuse _netdev,url={your_bucket_endpoint_url},allow_other,nonempty 0 0
```

Answer (score -3):

force it with -l

```
    sudo umount -l ${HOME}/mount_dir
```

Comment: It'd be useful to explain what this does, and why you recommend it over the approaches proposed by previous answers.