# Google Colab - Where is the output saved?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, drive, google-colaboratory

I am training a machine learning model on google's colab. I am using keras with tensorflow backend (python 3.6).
I am saving my model using the `model.save()` function provided by keras. When I call `model.save('model_name`)` where is the file saved? I cannot find it in my drive anywhere.

Comment: Did you mount your Drive?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: Check out this guide: https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d

Comment: So I mounted my drive and when I execute !ls i see the saved model. How do I download it / Where is it saved? I still do not understand :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, mount your drive:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Now, append your path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('drive/Project')
```

You should be able to see your files on your local and web-based drive using:

```
model.save('drive/Project/myModel.h5')
```

Comment: fuse: mountpoint is not empty
fuse: if you are sure this is safe, use the 'nonempty' mount option. How do I empty the mountpoint?

Comment: Maybe this could be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271101/what-happens-if-you-mount-to-a-non-empty-mount-point-with-fuse

Comment: Gave authorisation and mounted my drive. I am getting this error : Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = 'DL/Project/gen0.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 242)

Comment: from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is a bit late, I was also struggling with the same question.Then i found out mounting the drive in colab and then providing the drive path,the files will get stored in the google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
#using model.save_weights() to save the weights of the model in HDF5 format
model.save_weights("/content/gdrive/My Drive/weights.h5")
```

The file is saved in the drive with name "weights.h5"