# Where is the data downloaded through Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab and I clone some data from a repository. I can do `!ls` to see that the data is there. However I could not find the listed files anywhere.

Actually a question like this has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967752/google-colab-where-is-the-output-saved). However, in that question, the answers all responded with methods to *recover * the data , by mounting it. No one actually responded the question whih was *where* is the data.

So where is the data ?